# Multiple Actions in a Struts

Tags: model-view-controller, jakarta-ee, struts

I'm currently new to Java EE and I had just finished my class in Java EE. We were asked to create a program with add, edit and delete using MVC Struts 1.

So my question is, how to do it with multiple actions? Do you have any tutorial which explains how to create a successful web app using Struts?

Comment: Why use a framework that hasn't been updated since 2008, and which has been obsoleted for a long time by much more modern frameworks like Stripes, Spring MVC, Play, etc? Struts 1 is dead. It shouldn't be used anymore for new projects. If you really want to use STruts1, then look at the [javadoc of DispatchAction](http://struts.apache.org/1.3.10/apidocs/org/apache/struts/actions/DispatchAction.html) and of its subclasses. And read the [Sruts user guide](http://struts.apache.org/1.3.10/userGuide/index.html)

Comment: @JB Nizet well i have no background yet to java..and we don't know why the scholarship program still teach us struts rather than Spring or struts2..for a beginner, what would you advice sir? I have no experience yet on java programming.

Comment: I would advise Stripes. It's simple, efficient, very well designed and documented, based on JEE, and focused only on the presentation layer (unlike Spring).

Comment: @JB Nizet ok thanks sir..i'll try that..thanks for answering..^^

Comment: I would advise to look at JSF. This is the easiest MVC framework to begin with, and it's already part of Java EE. No need to download, install or configure anything.

Answer (score 0):

**[BEST LINK TO LEARN](http://www.rameshsengani.in/vaannila/struts/struts-tutorial/struts-tutorial.html)**

register.jsp

```
    <form name="myform">
    // other inputs going here
    <input type="button" name="add" value="add" id="add" onclick="submitAction(this)">
    <input type="button" name="update" value="update" id="update" onclick="submitAction(this)">
    <input type="button" name="delete" value="delete" id="delete" onclick="submitAction(this)">
    </form>
```

javascript:

```
function submitAction(actType)
{
document.myform.action = actType.id;
document.myform.submit();

}

<action name="MyUpdateAction" type="test.MyUpdateAction" path="/update" input="/register.jsp">
  <forward name="success" path="/updated.jsp" />
  <forward name="failure" path="/failure.jsp" />
</action>
<action name="MyAddAction" tepe="test.MyAddAction" path="/add" input="/register.jsp">
  <forward name="success" path="/added.jsp" />
  <forward name="failure" path="/failure.jsp" />
</action>
<action name="MyDeleteAction" type="test.MyDeleteAction" path="/delete" input="/register.jsp">
  <forward name="success" path="/deleted.jsp" />
  <forward name="failure" path="/failure.jsp" />
</action>
```

Struts Actions in package test:

```
 public class MyUpdateAction extends org.apache.struts.action.Action {
    public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception 
    {       //do update Stuff...
        if () {
            return mapping.findForward("success");
        } else {
                return mapping.findForward("failure");}
    }

    public class MyAddAction extends org.apache.struts.action.Action {
    public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception 
        {           //do add Stuff...       
        if () {
            return mapping.findForward("success");
        } else {
                return mapping.findForward("failure");}
        }

    public class MyDeleteAction extends org.apache.struts.action.Action {
    public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception 
        {       //do delete Stuff...    
        if () {
            return mapping.findForward("success");
        } else {
                return mapping.findForward("failure");}
        }
```